# MFC Application hanged after the 'co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync' call

Tags: dll, mfc, dependencies, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I have one MFC application which uses the BLE DLL. The BLE library will take care of the device scan, connection, etc.

I have tried to link the BLE DLL dynamically. The Bluetooth device scanning is completed without any issue. When I tried to call the **ConnectToDevice** API from the BLE DLL the issue occurs.

The API is working in other C++ frameworks except MFC. I have just created a dialog base MFC application and call the BLE Library APIs from the simple button click event.

This is the sample code

```
 fire_and_forget SensorDeviceInfo::ConnectToDevice(condition_variable& signal, bool& bConnected)
 {

     // Returns a BluetoothLEDevice object for the given Id and initiate a connection
     m_BluetoothLEDevice = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(GetId());
    
     if (m_BluetoothLEDevice == nullptr)
     {
         LogError(m_Log, __func__, "Failed to connect to device.");
     }

     if (m_BluetoothLEDevice != nullptr)
     {
        m_ConnectionStatusEventToken = m_BluetoothLEDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged({ this, 
                &SensorDeviceInfo::ConnectionStatusChangeHandler });
     }

   signal.notify_one();
}
```

Since this is an asynchronous call, I have used condition variable to block the thread until the function completes.

```
            mutex mtxConnect;
            unique_lock lockConnect(mtxConnect);
            condition_variable cvConnect;

            // Connect to the sensor ble device
            m_CurrentDevice->ConnectToDevice(cvConnect, bConnected);
            cvConnect.wait(lockConnect);
```

While debugging the application, the call enter in the **FromIdAsync** place, but after some time it is getting hanged and the Call Stack get disappeared.

I am using VS2019 and the latest redistributable package(2019).

While checking the Dependencies tool, I can see some DLLs are missing from the Windows\System32 folder.
The missing DLLs are **api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll, api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll, api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll**. Here api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll, api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll are available in other windows locations.
But the DLL api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll is not present in the system.

Below is the dependency issues given by Dependencies tool

[image: Dependencies]

I have checked the *mfc140.dll* from other colleagues machine. The dependency problem is present in their machines too.

I don’t know whether this DLL missing problem is the main cause of our Library API ConnectToDevice.

Comment: That's awkward code for many reasons. It spins off an asynchronous task, and then decides to wait for completion **synchronously**. Synchronization is way redundant, too. I mean, if you *do* want to execute `ConnectToDevice` synchronously, just have it return an [IAsyncAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncaction) and call the C++/WinRT extension function `get()` on it. Though, really, you certainly do not want to block your UI thread, ever.

Comment: Also, passing references into coroutines is *always* a bug that's just waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried the same as you said. I have tried the [IAsyncAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncaction?view=winrt-20348) & [IAsyncOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperation-1?view=winrt-20348).
Now the APIs are working and I can now block the working thread as well.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The issue is still coming in my original MFC application. In the sample MFC app it was working without any issue.

Comment: I seem to recall that the BLE API is somewhat finicky when it comes to which thread executes which call. While it is possible to offload the `FromIdAsync` call onto a threadpool thread, you should return back to the original thread prior to setting the event callback. The second sample in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind) explains how to return to the calling thread.

Comment: Since I don't have anything to display in the UI thread, I go with the [offloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#offloading-work-onto-the-windows-thread-pool) scenario. 

`co_await winrt::resume_background();`

Above code actually solved my issue.
Thanks for the immediate help.

Comment: I'm skeptical, though if you don't have a reason to make `ConnectToDevice` asynchronous then simply don't. Turn it into a regular function, and replace the `co_await` operator with `FromIdAsync(GetId()).get()`. There aren't any other suspension points to deal with, and after this change everything just runs on a single thread. Though you probably **do** want an asynchronous implementation so as to not freeze the UI.

Comment: Oh god! Why didn't I think about it earlier. Thanks @IInspectable for all the valuable comments. I just removed the `co_await` and simply used `.get()` with the WinRT APIs itself.